# Assembly input-output

Tags: assembly, io, fasm

I have 2 programs: one of them does input-output(C++), and another calculates formula(Assembly). They work with each other.

This program does input-output:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int calc(int a, int b, int c, int d);

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout<<"a:"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"b:"<<endl;
    int b;
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"c:"<<endl;
    int c;
    cin>>c;

    cout<<"d:"<<endl;
    int d;
    cin>>d;

    int calculation = calc(a,b,c,d);
    cout << "5*a-c*d+7*b-2=" <<calculation<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this program calculates result:

```
format ELF

public calc

calc: 
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
label a dword at ebp+8
label b dword at ebp+12
label c dword at ebp+16
label d dword at ebp+20

mov eax, [a]
mov ebx, 5
mul ebx
mov ecx, eax

mov eax, [c]
mov ebx, [d]
mul ebx
sub ecx, eax


mov eax, [b]
mov ebx, 7
mul ebx
add eax, ecx

sub eax, 2
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp     
ret
```

Can you please help me doing input-output also in Assembly (without C++ program)? I'm not sure how to do it in this example.
Appreciate any help.

Comment: What assembler (FASM?) do you want to use? How did you assemble, compile and link the two programs?

Comment: @rkhb I use fasm, to compile both program I use ' g++ -m32 calc.cpp calcul.o -o a.out'

Answer (score 1):

It's virtually impossible to program `cin` and `cout` by hand in assembly. But you can use the functions `printf` and `scanf` of the C-library which is a subset of the C++-standard:

```
format ELF
public main
extrn printf
extrn scanf
extrn fflush

section '.text' executable

calc:
label .a dword at ebp+8                 ; Labels with dot are local labels
label .b dword at ebp+12
label .c dword at ebp+16
label .d dword at ebp+20

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, [.a]
    mov ebx, 5
    mul ebx
    mov ecx, eax
    mov eax, [.c]
    mov ebx, [.d]
    mul ebx
    sub ecx, eax
    mov eax, [.b]
    mov ebx, 7
    mul ebx
    add eax, ecx
    sub eax, 2

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret

main:
label .calculation dword at ebp-4       ; Labels with dot are local labels
label .a dword at ebp-8
label .b dword at ebp-12
label .c dword at ebp-16
label .d dword at ebp-20

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 20                         ; Space for the local variables

    lea eax, [in_msg]
    push eax
    call printf                         ; printf ("a: ");
    add esp, 4

    lea eax, [.a]                       ; Pointer to .a (effective address of .a)
    push eax
    push scan_fmt
    call scanf                          ; scanf (" %d", &a);
    add esp, 8                          ; Clean up the stack

    lea eax, [in_msg+4]
    push eax
    call printf                         ; printf ("b: ");
    add esp, 4

    lea eax, [.b]                       ; Pointer to .a (effective address of .a)
    push eax
    push scan_fmt
    call scanf                          ; scanf (" %d", &b);
    add esp, 8                          ; Clean up the stack

    lea eax, [in_msg+8]
    push eax
    call printf                         ; printf ("c: ");
    add esp, 4

    lea eax, [.c]                       ; Pointer to .a (effective address of .a)
    push eax
    push scan_fmt
    call scanf                          ; scanf (" %d", &c);
    add esp, 8                          ; Clean up the stack

    lea eax, [in_msg+12]
    push eax
    call printf                         ; printf ("d: ");

    add esp, 4
    lea eax, [.d]                       ; Pointer to .a (effective address of .a)
    push eax
    push scan_fmt
    call scanf                          ; scanf (" %d", &d);
    add esp, 8                          ; Clean up the stack

    push [.d]                           ; Call by value
    push [.c]                           ; Call by value
    push [.b]                           ; Call by value
    push [.a]                           ; Call by value
    call calc                           ; EAX = calc (a,b,c,d)
    add esp, 16                         ; Clean up the stack
    mov [.calculation], eax             ; Store result for later use

    push [.calculation]
    push out_fmt
    call printf                         ; printf("5*a-c*d+7*b-2=%d\n",calculation);
    add esp,8                           ; Clean up the stack

    leave
    ret

section '.data' writeable

    out_fmt     db "5*a-c*d+7*b-2=%d", 10, 0
    scan_fmt    db " %d",0
    in_msg      db "a: ",0,"b: ",0,"c: ",0,"d: ",0
```

Assemble, link and run it with

```
fasm calc.asm
g++ -m32 -o calc calc.o
./calc
```

Instead of `g++` you can use `gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions from C library (libc) from within assembly code. Details how to invoke the C functions depend on which assembler is used. Also which registers and/or stack is used for function parameters and in which order depend on executable target (32-bit or 64-bit). For example yasm assembler syntax for calling scanf function on 64-bit Linux can be:

```
segment .data
format:  db  "%d"  ;format string used in scanf("%d", &var)
var: dd 123    ;variable where we want to read input to (initialized to a random number 123)
segment .text
global main
extern scanf
main:
lea rax, [var]
lea edi, [format]
xor eax, eax
call  scanf
```

In order to produce an executable file:

- `yasm -f elf64 usingClib.s`
- `gcc usingClib.o -o usingClib`

I suggest using `gcc` instead `ld` as gcc by default links the C library.